# Find the address of the wallet know almost all the letters

Tags: addresses

I want to find ethereum address and I have almost all the letters. The beginning of the wallet: 0xb6b2ceb624a6b667e67af1893b16706baec21 
But how can I find remaining letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code using web3.js 1.0-beta, which failed to find any accounts with positive balances:

```js
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('https://mainnet.infura.io');

const start = '0xb6b2ceb624a6b667e67af1893b16706baec21';

async function main() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4096; i++) {
        const end = web3.utils.padLeft(web3.utils.toHex(i).substring(2), 3);
        const address = start + end;
        const balance = parseInt(await web3.eth.getBalance(address), 10);

        if (balance > 0) {
            console.log(`${address} has a balance of ${balance} wei.`);
        }
    }
}

main();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 digits missing and all the possible combinaisons are valid address from `0xb6b2ceb624a6b667e67af1893b16706baec21000` ([here](https://etherscan.io/address/0xb6b2ceb624a6b667e67af1893b16706baec21000)) to `0xb6b2ceb624a6b667e67af1893b16706baec21fff` ([here](https://etherscan.io/address/0xb6b2ceb624a6b667e67af1893b16706baec21fff))

You have no choice than checking all the combinaisons: `16^3 = 4096`

If you are sure that the address you are looking for has a positive balance, you can write an algorithm which will check for each possible combinaison the balance and extract only the address with positive balance.

For example:

```
const provider     = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/");
const web3         = new Web3(provider);

const alphabet = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f];
const input = "0xb6b2ceb624a6b667e67af1893b16706baec21";

for (x in alphabet) { 
    for (y in alphabet) {
        for (z in alphabet) {
            let address = input + x + y + z;
            let balance = new BigNumber(web3.eth.getBalance(address));

            if(balance.greaterThan(new BigNumber(0)) {
               console.log(address + "=" + web3.fromWei(balance, "ether"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran something similar and didn't find any accounts with positive balances.

Answer (score 0):

You can write SQL query using LIKE syntax with wildcard character %.

```
SELECT *
FROM ethereum.transactions
WHERE TO_ADDRESS LIKE '0xb6b2ceb624a6b667e67af1893b16706baec21%'
```

[See it in action](https://app.flipsidecrypto.com/velocity/queries/d57e21e5-9523-4793-8073-eaa631ed49db) on Flipside.