# Find ERC20/Polygon address with the beginning and end

Tags: erc-20, addresses, nodejs, polygon

I found this post: [Find the address of the wallet know almost all the letters](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/66050/find-the-address-of-the-wallet-know-almost-all-the-letters)

I'm looking for a code to find an address on Polygon with a beginning and the end.

I have this information: **0x858b...4B7d**. Do you think it's possible to find it?

I tried flipsidecrypto.xyz but I got an error (i know the address made a multiple transactions two months ago)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

An address starting with `0x858b` and ending with `4B7d` doesn't seem to exist on the Polygon mainnet.

But to answer the how-to question so that it might be useful:

There are many different ways to do this, but the easiest and quickest one is to use dune.com & SQL:

1. Go to dune.com
2. Create > New query > Raw > polygon transactions
3. Put in the following SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM polygon.transactions
WHERE (LOWER(CAST("from" AS VARCHAR)) LIKE '0x858b%' AND LOWER(CAST("from" AS VARCHAR)) LIKE '%4B7d')
LIMIT 1000
```

If you are certain that you have the known characters of the address correctly, feel free to just play around with the query & explore the results (eg just search for the starting `0x858b` and explore the results, or the ending characters, or the case, or search on Ethereum etc).